# Print dereferenced values from list in GDB

Tags: python, c++, gdb

I am looking at a core file in gdb. I have a std::list of pointers to objects that are on the heap.  Debugging with GDB, printing the list returns a list of addresses. That makes sense.

I can print the dereferenced object of the first element in the list easily i.e. 'print *$1.my_list.front()'. I want to see the contents of each element in the list. I am having trouble printing each element dereferenced. Is there a straightfoward way to print each dereferenced element?

I would consider myself a gdb beginner and generally muddle through when I need to use it. I know there are examples online of importing python scripts although most examples show debugging a running program. If you are also aware of any good resources for a newb to learn more about gdb best practices that would be most appreciated.

Comment: Also check the source code of xmethods/pretty printers to see how can the members be accessed. (although if xmethods are already available then no need to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gdb has pretty-printers for most of the standard library and thus just `print your_list` should be enough in most cases. However, since you have a list of pointers and you want to see the referenced objects you have to get one element of the list and then deference it by using `p *your_list.front()` as you have already done. For the other elements besides the first one, you can do `p *(your_list.front()+1)`, `p *(your_list.front()+2)`, etc. Using pointer arithmetic like this you get the address of another element **before** dereferencing it.

You can also treat the first element as the *start of an array* and see the whole "array" using `@SIZE` in the address. That is a special syntax in gdb to see a memory region as a C array. Suppose you want to see the first 4 elements in the list. You can use `p *your_list.front()@4`.

---

**Note:** The main difference of debugging from a core file or from a running program is that you don't have a running process when you debug from a core file. That means that you can't call functions when you debug from a core file unless there is an [xmethod](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Xmethods-In-Python.html) defined in gdb for the method you are trying to call. gdb also has many xmethods already defined and that is why you are able to call `.front()` as well as other methods such as `.size()` in your list.

Comment: `front()` just returns a reference to the first element of the collection. When it is used to do arithmetic such as `your_list.front()+1`, this value is not the value of the element of index 1. `begin()` is used to iterate through the list.